# After form submission clicking save button I want to redirect to its own edit page with id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This is my save and redirect function in blade page:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success" onclick="createOrUpdateBusiness('{{ URL::to("transactions/addUpdateBusinessEntry") }}', 'addBusinessForm', false, false,'{{ URL::to("transactions/businessEntry") }}', true)" class="btn btn-warning">Save</a>
```

Here is the redirection take place and redirect to its table list page.. I want to change this and redirect to its edit page

```
{{ URL::to("transactions/businessEntry") }}
```

This is url of my edit page but when I am trying pass this url it's not working

```
var URL_redirect="{{ URL::to('transactions/addEditBusinessEntry?id='.$id) }}";
```

Please help - I'm a beginner in Laravel

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
var URL_redirect="{{ URL::to('transactions/addEditBusinessEntry) }}/{{$id}}";
```

And your route should be like this

```
Route::get('transactions/addEditBusinessEntry/{id}', 'NameController@your_method');
```

Comment: How to pass this id on this function  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" onclick="createOrUpdateBussiness('{{ URL::to("transactions/addUpdateBussinessEntry") }}', 'addBussinessForm', false, false,'{{ URL::to("transactions/addEditBussinessEntry") }}', true)" class="btn btn-warning">Save</a>

Comment: _This is my route_  ` Route::get('/addEditBussinessEntry', ['uses' => 'Transaction@addEditBussinessEntryAction']);`

Comment: I am not clear what you want.

`edit route`

`update route `

both are need to you